# Full screen background for a website - samsung default web browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, browser

My goal is to have the same effect as

```
background-size: cover;
```

but this property does not seem to work with some web browsers, like the default browser of samsung galaxy note and samsung neo plus. I tried to mix the style with some javascript, and I made the following code:

```
<script>
    var w = screen.width + "px";
    var h = "auto";
    var size = w+" "+h;
    var style ="background-size: "+size+"; -webkit-background-size: "+size+"; -moz-background-size: "+size+"; -o-background-size: "+size+";";
    document.write('<body style="'+style+'">');
</script>
```

But this solution still doesn't work with the browsers mentioned above.

Is there another way to achieve this background behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get expected behavior by giving fixed height to html/body tags.

```
html{
 height:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 }
body{
 min-height:100%;
 }
```